# Does Googlebot cache JavaScript files between two pages if they expire in one year?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, googlebot, javascript

My question is about javascript websites.

Suppose GoogleBot has crawled `example.com/index.html?id=1`

Does it request all the javascript files again when crawling `example.com/index.html?id=2`?

`index.html?id=1` and `index.html?id=2` have identical javascript files, but their generated contents are different.

The javascript files are included like so

`<script src="data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Here is the code for cache control in the `.htaccess`.

`ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"`

Comment: I do not believe that Google caches resource files such as JS at all. Or not longer than it takes to render the page and processes it.

Comment: @closetnoc I struggle with the idea that Google doesn't cache resource files "at all". If Google was in the process of crawling 100 or so pages then I would think it a complete waste if it didn't at least cache the common resources between these 100 or so pages. But at the same time I certainly can't see Google honouring a cache time of "one year" (or even _one week_) as this could potentially/inadvertantly kill a site if the webmaster/developer has made a _simple_ caching error. In an ideal world I would perhaps expect the SE to honour the caching directives; but alas the world is pretty far

Comment: ... from ideal.

Comment: @DocRoot I remember reading a lenthy paper outlining the difficulty of caching JS when so much of it is the same resources. At that time, the thought was that caching JS was a waste and yielded no advantage. I can see caching long enough to the work that is needed of course. After that, what would be the point? The cache is supposed to be helpful, but not to replace the experience of going to the sites page. We did have a question a while ago where the OP was updating his JS regularly and feared breaking any cached page. I do not remember the consensus on that question if there was one.

Comment: @DocRoot I thought I would see if a cached page would make references to any cached resource including JS. I used my tablet and I do not see that I can access a cached page. [insert grin] Ooopppsss! So much for that thought!

Comment: @DocRoot I do not profess to be an authority on the matter. I just cannot imagine it. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, I would total agree with your idea @DocRoot: _... but not to replace the experience of going to the sites page._

Comment: I will be examining this by tracking GoogleBot activity in such a website, where a resource file is shared with a lot of pages. If the there will be a request for `data.js` per request for `index.html` by GoogleBot, then it may not cache resource files at all. Thank you, everybody, for your comments.

Comment: @Siamak Be sure to report back your findings. :)

Comment: Of course, as soon as I get something to share 